# Cannot play facebook Live Video in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, uiwebview

I'm reading live videos from the facebook Api in swift. The request url is:

https://graph.facebook.com/miPageID/live_videos

The answer I get is an array of videos, each one has somenthing like this.

> {
>       description = "Video description";
>       "embed_html" = "https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=1041870252579934\"
>   width=\"400\" height=\"400\" frameborder=\"0\">";
>       id = 1041870255905313;
>       "permalink_url" = "/1040317772727228/videos/1041870252571980/";
>       status = LIVE; 
>   }

Then I load the video in a UIWebView. If the video is already published I can see it without problems, but when it is in live mode I can't see it.

In safari I get the same behavior that i get in  UIWebView. Here is an image so you can see what I'm getting.

**Safari vs Chrome** (In chrome I can see it, but not in safari)
https://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7425/27407837763_92d61270f2_b.jpg

Does any one know how can I solve this?, maybe some third party library or something.

Sorry for my english and thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Video live are streamed chunk by chunk. Any chunk is a `.ts` file, where **TS stands for Transport Stream**.

In iOS to play live video as you do with a normal video, you need to do some work in more.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) you can read all the *Apple documentation* about **HTTP Live Streaming**, to understand better how this works on iOS.
It is not an easy topic, indeed there are paid frameworks like [this one](https://github.com/iMoreApps/ffmpeg-avplayer-for-ios-tvos) which are ready to be used for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore for facebook Live in iOS

```
 self.vcSession = [[VCSimpleSession alloc] initWithVideoSize:CGSizeMake(854, 480) frameRate:30 bitrate:1000000 useInterfaceOrientation:NO];
 [self.view addSubview:self.vcSession.previewView];
 self.vcSession.previewView.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 320, 240);//self.view.bounds;
 self.vcSession.delegate = self;
 [self.vcSession startRtmpSessionWithURL:@"your rtmp:URL "andStreamKey:@"your stream key"];
```

Where vcSeesion is object of Class VCSsimpleSession which is created in .h file.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.